# How can I create an Alert Box in a PHP file?

Tags: php

I need a simple ok alert box in my php file.

Comment: do you mean javascript `alert("This is an alert");`?

Comment: Use JavaScript, is the best thing I can tell you

Answer (score 3):

Not possible in PHP, because it runs on a server. The alert box is a client side feature. You must use Javascript.

Comment: just to be sure, i can integrate javascript in my php file just by opening a tag?

Comment: It seems, that you should read the basics from the manual once more. Everything within `<?php ?>` is treated as PHP code, so everything outside this tags is send to the browser "as it is", in most cases its HTML. And in HTML you can integrate/link Javascript code.

Answer (score 3):

Try that:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("Text!") </script>';
```